# Get the solution to the differential equation $\cos y \sin2x dx +(cos^2y - cos^2x)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was helping somebody on some math problems when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> Get the solution to the differential equation $$\cos y \sin2x dx +(\cos^2y - \cos^2x)dy = 0$$

**My work**

I was able to search the internet on how to get the solution to the differential equation shown above but I do not understand the way.

We could perhaps rearrange the above differential equation into the form

$$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$$

With the form above, we could see if the given differential equation is variable-separable, homogenous or an exact-type.

Testing the given differential equation as variable-separable:

**No. We can't. The differential equation above isn't variable-separable.**

Testing the given differential equation as homogenous:

$F(x,y)$ is a homogenous function of degree $n$ in $x$ and $y$ provided $F(kx,ky)$ = $k^nF(x,y)$. For example, $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 \sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ are homogenous functions of degree $2$ in $x$ and $y$. With that in mind...

Looking at the first term $\cos y \sin2x$:
$$F(x,y) = \cos y \sin2x$$
$$F(kx,ky) = \cos (ky) \sin(2kx)$$
Getting deeper, we conclude that
$$F(kx,ky) \neq k^nF(x,y)$$

Looking at the second term $\cos^2y - \cos^2x$:
$$F(x,y) = \cos^2y - \cos^2x$$
$$F(kx,ky) = \cos^2(ky) - \cos^2(kx)$$
Getting deeper, we conclude that
$$F(kx,ky) \neq k^nF(x,y)$$

The terms themselves must be homogenous if the differential equations are homogenous.

**No. We can't. The differential equation above isn't homogenous.**

Testing the given differential equation if it is an exact-type:

A necessary condition for a differential equation to be exact is

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

So getting the expression for $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$:

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\cos y \sin2x) $$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \sin 2x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\cos y) $$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \sin 2x(-\sin y)$$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = -\sin y \sin 2x$$

So getting the expression for $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$:

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\cos^2y - \cos^2x) $$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\cos^2x) $$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos 2x\right) $$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = \sin 2x $$

We see that $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, so **the given differential equation isn't exact** either.

Let's try converting it into linear differential equation.

Let's try rearranging the given differential equation above into a Bernoulli equation, having the form

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x)$$
Then...

$$\cos y \sin2x dx +(\cos^2y - \cos^2x)dy = 0$$
$$\frac{\cos y \sin2x dx}{dx} +\frac{(\cos^2y - \cos^2x)dy}{dx} = \frac{0}{dx}$$
$$\cos y \sin2x + (\cos^2y - \cos^2x)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\frac{\cos y \sin2x}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x} + \frac{\cos^2y - \cos^2x}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{0}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x}$$
$$\frac{\cos y \sin2x}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x} + \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\cos y \sin2x}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x} = 0$$

Screw that. We couldn't even discern what is the expression of $P(x)y$ because the expression $\frac{\cos y \sin2x}{\cos^2y - \cos^2x}$ is irreducible. We can't separate $x$'s from $y$'s.

How do we get the solution  of the differential equation above?

Comment: I may suggest using substitutions: $X=sin(x)$ and $Y=cos(y)$. However, after some work, I don’t think that helps much. In general, I think there is no closed form solution for this equation. This can be solved by some algorithms like Picard’s method.

Answer (score 2):

***Just a little hint***

This is not a full solution ...

$$\cos(y)\sin(2x)x'=-\cos^2(y)+ {\cos^2(x)}$$
$$\sin(2x)x'=-\cos(y)+\frac {\cos^2(x)}{\cos(y)}$$
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)x'=-\cos(y)+\frac {1-\sin^2(x)}{\cos(y)}$$
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)x'+\frac {\sin^2(x)}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)+\frac {1}{\cos(y)}$$
$$2\sin(x)\cos(x)x'+\frac {\sin^2(x)}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$$
$$2\sin(x)(\sin(x))'+\frac {\sin^2(x)}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$$
Sustitute $h=\sin(x)$ for a better expression
$$2hh'+\frac {h^2}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$$
$$(h^2)'+\frac {h^2}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$$
Substitute $g(y)=h^2(y)-1$
$$\boxed{g'(y)+\frac {g(y)}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)}$$

$$........$$
We have reduced the first equation  to the canonical form of a first order linear equation. But it does not mean that it's easy to integrate such ode. Especially if it involves Gaussian like integrals...

***Edit*** 
Maybe the  ODE could be solved with $tan(x/2)$ susbtitution's formula...
when I write $h=\sin(x)$ it means $h(y)=\sin(x(y))$ both x, and h are functions of the variable y.And so is g ( g(y))  too.

Comment: $h = \sin(x)$ and $g = h^2 = \sin^2(x)$, then what is $g(y)$?

Comment: g is a function of y ......because I considered x as the function and y as the variable @AlexanderJ93  and $\sin(x)$ is a fucntion of the variable y Note in the first lines I considered x' and not y'

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I don't understand....Why from this expression $(h^2)'+\frac {h^2}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$, when we let $g(y)=h^2(y)-1$, it instantly becomes $\boxed{g'(y)+\frac {g(y)}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)}$?

Comment: @PalautotKa   Look at the value of f(y) .$$f(y)=-\cos(y)+\frac {1}{\cos(y)}$$  I just use that for simplicity ..thats all  $$(h^2)'+\frac {h^2}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)+\frac {1}{\cos(y)}$$ $$(h^2)'+\frac {h^2-1}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)$$$$g'+\frac {g}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)$$

Comment: I understand now. But what about, in the expression $(h^2)'+\frac {h^2}{\cos(y)}=f(y)$, looking at $(h^2)'$, I believe it really means $d(h^2)$. But when you let $g(y)=h^2(y)-1$, the expression $\boxed{g'(y)+\frac {g(y)}{\cos(y)}=-\cos(y)}$. Why $(h^2)'$ or $d(h^2)$ equals $g'(y)$? I thought $g'(y) = 2h(y)$?

Comment: @PalautotKa  $g'$ means $ g' =\frac {dg}{dy}$ derivative wrt y  So $g' =(h^2-1)' \implies g'=(h^2)'$ the derivatives of a constant is 0 so the -1 vanishes

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just now I do not have the time to type the answer in latex. I'll do it tomorrow if it appears useful.

This is only a quick overview, without care about the signs of the square roots. Hoping it will be an useful hint.

[image]

The solution is on the form $x(y)$. Probably, there is no closed form for the inverse function $y(x)$.

Note :

$(1+\sin(y))\cos^2(x)=c\:\cos(y)-cos^2(y)-\cos(y)\sin^{-1}(\cos(y))$

$\frac{(1+\sin(y))\cos^2(x)}{\cos(y)}=c-\cos(y)-\sin^{-1}(\cos(y))=C-\cos(y)+y$

$$y-\cos(y)-\frac{(1+\sin(y))\cos^2(x)}{\cos(y)}=-C$$
This is consistent with the expected solution (doesn't matter the sign of $C$).

Comment: I admired your effort.....I can wait for your answer. Just take it easy. No rush.....:-)

Comment: The solution of the differential equation I've seen on Internet is $y−\cos (y)−\cos ^2(x)\frac{1+sin(y)}{cos(y)}=C$. They got the solution because they made the given differential equation, which is an inexact d.e, into an exact d.e. I don't know if the solution is right. Maybe we can work it out.....

Comment: The solutions are both correct, it's just that @JJacquelin integrated $$\int\frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=c-\sin^{-1}t$$ rather than $$\int\frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\cos^{-1}t-C$$

Comment: @Palautot Ka: The above solution is consistent with the solution you found on internet (See the added note at end of my answer). So, no need to waste time to re-edit my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\begin{aligned}\\
> \cos y\sin 2xdx+(\cos^2y-\cos^2x)dy&=0\\
> \end{aligned}$$

It is of the form:
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
So, here,
$$M=\cos y\sin 2x, N=(\cos^2y-\cos^2x)$$
$$\therefore \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-\sin y\sin 2x\\
\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\sin 2x\\
\begin{align}
\therefore \frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{M}&=\frac{-\sin y\sin 2x -\sin 2x}{\cos y\sin 2x}\\
&=-\frac{\sin 2x(1+\sin y)}{\cos y\sin 2x}\\
&=-(sec y+tan y)=-g(y)\\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\text{I.F.} &=e^{-\int g(y)dy}\\
&=e^{\int(sec y+tan y)dy}\\
&=e^{\ln(sec y+tan y)+\ln(sec y)}\\
&=sec y(sec y+tan y)\\
\end{align}$$
Multiplying the equation with the integrating factor,
$$\begin{align}
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\cos y\sin 2x \sec y(\sec y+\tan y)dx&+(\cos^2y-\cos^2x)\sec y(\sec y+\tan y)dy&=0\\
\end{aligned}}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies\sin 2x(\sec y+\tan y)dx&+(\cos^2y-\cos^2x)(\sec^2y+\sec y&\tan  y)dy=0\\
\end{aligned}}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies\sin 2x(\sec y+\tan  y)dx&+(1-\sec^2y\cos^2x+\sin y-\cos^2x \sec y&\tan y)dy&=0\\
\end{aligned}}\\
\end{align}$$
$\text{which is an exact equation.}$
So, the solution is,
$$\begin{align}
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\int_{(\text{y const})}Mdx+&\int(\text{terms of N not containing x})dy=c\\
\end{aligned}}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies\int\sin 2x(\sec y+\tan y)dx+&\int(1+\sin y)dy=c\\
\end{aligned}}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies -\frac{1}{2}\cos2x(\sec y+\tan y)+y-\cos y&=c\\
\end{aligned}}\\
\end{align}$$